# Is there a good way to determine the package of a type in a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm writing a macro that needs to determine the package of the type it's parameterised on. It's possible with something like:

```
def macroImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
  import c.universe._

  val typ = weakTypeOf[T]
  val pkg = typ.typeSymbol.fullName.stripSuffix(s".${typ.typeSymbol.name}")
}
```

but this feels distinctly hacky. Is there a better approach?

Comment: weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.owner.fullName. That'll work if the class is top-level. Otherwise, you'll have to call .owner repeatedly until you reach something that has Symbol.isPackageClass = true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This need not be in a `macro`, but nothing here would preclude doing so.  As long as you have a type symbol, you can continually check the type's `owner` until you find a package:

```
def owners[T : WeakTypeTag] = Iterator.iterate(weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.owner)(_.owner).takeWhile(!_.isPackageClass)
```

The last element of this iterator will be the package symbol.  If all you care about is the package name, you could do:

```
def package[T : WeakTypeTag] = owners[T].last.fullName
```

[The documentation on symbol reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) has a good note about the `owner` property (my bolding):

> Symbols are organized in a hierarchy. For example, a symbol that represents a parameter of a method is *owned* by the corresponding method symbol, a method symbol is *owned* by its enclosing class, trait, or object, **a class is *owned* by a containing package and so on**.
>
> If a symbol does not have an owner, for example, because it refers to a top-level entity, such as a top-level package, then its owner is the special `NoSymbol` singleton object. Representing a missing symbol, `NoSymbol` is commonly used in the API to denote an empty or default value. Accessing the owner of `NoSymbol` throws an exception. See the API docs for the general interface provided by type [`Symbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/scala/reflect/api/Symbols$SymbolApi.html).